# How to print table element in selenium?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, arraylist

I am trying to print table data element by using the code shown here; there is no error, but the result is not as expected - please help.

```
import java.util.List;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import java.time.Duration;

public class Table {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

        driver.manage().window().maximize();

        driver.get("https://www.techlistic.com/2017/02/automate-demo-web-table-with-selenium.html");

        // TABLE

        // TR - ROWS

        // TH - COLUMN HEADER

        // TR - OVERALL ROWS

        // TD - ROWS DATA

        WebElement table = driver.findElement(By.id("customers"));

        List<WebElement> rows = table.findElements(By.xpath("//table[@id='customers']/tbody/tr"));
        System.out.println(rows.size());

        List<WebElement> column = table.findElements(By.xpath("//table[@id='customers']/tbody/tr/th"));
        System.out.println(column.size());

        List<WebElement> rd = table.findElements(By.xpath("//table[@id='customers']/tbody/tr/td"));
        System.out.println(rd.size());

        for (WebElement e : column) {
            System.out.println(e.getText());
        }

        for (int i = 1; i <= column.size(); i++) {
            List<WebElement> thiteration = driver
                    .findElements(By.xpath("//table[@id='customers']/tbody/tr/th[" + i + "]"));
            // System.out.println("The Headings are " + thiteration.getText());
            for (WebElement e2 : thiteration) {
                System.out.println(e2.getText());
            }
            List<WebElement> tditeration = driver
                    .findElements(By.xpath("//table[@id='customers']/tbody/tr/td[" + i + "]"));
            for (WebElement e1 : tditeration) {
                System.out.println(e1.getText());
            }
            // System.out.println("The Row Datas are " + tditeration.getText());
            Thread.sleep(Duration.ofSeconds(3));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please implement below solution and o/p is also added:

```
public class Test {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.addArguments("--remote-allow-origins=*");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);

    driver.get("https://www.techlistic.com/2017/02/automate-demo-web-table-with-selenium.html");
    
    WebElement table = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table[@id='customers']"));

    List<WebElement> listRows = table.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));
    List<WebElement> listHeaders = listRows.get(0).findElements(By.tagName("th"));

    for(int header=0; header<listHeaders.size();header++){
        System.out.println(listHeaders.get(header).getText());
        for(int row=1; row<listRows.size(); row++){
            System.out.println(listRows.get(row).findElements(By.xpath("td")).get(header).getText());
        }
        System.out.println("\n");
    }

    driver.quit();
}
```

}

Output

```
   Company
   Google
   Meta
   Microsoft
   Island Trading
   Adobe
   Amazon


   Contact
   Maria Anders
   Francisco Chang
   Roland Mendel
   Helen Bennett
   Yoshi Tannamuri
   Giovanni Rovelli


   Country
   Germany
   Mexico
   Austria
   UK
   Canada
   Italy
```